# How to change legend edges from round to sharp corners

Tags: matplotlib, formatting, legend

how can I change the edges of the frames for legends generated in matplotlib from round to having sharp corners?

Answer (score 5):

Let's use [`set_boxstyle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.BoxStyle.html):

```
from seaborn import load_dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = load_dataset('tips')

df.head()

ax = df.plot('sex',['total_bill','tip'])
ax.legend().get_frame().set_boxstyle('Round', pad=0.2, rounding_size=2)
```

Output:

[image]